# Given this definition of a relation, describe it explicitly

Tags: relations

> Given: $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ and $R \subseteq A^2$, where $aRb \leftrightarrow b− a = 1$,
>   give $R$ explicitly:
>   $$R = ?$$

How would I got about solving this? I was thinking $R = \{[2,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,4],[6,4],[7,6]\}$ since these are combinations result into 1.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right, but you've got your tuples backwards. "$aRb$" means "$b-a=1$," so e.g. $1R2$, not $2R1$ as you've written, etc. (Note that order matters in relations, in general.)

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid now, I was looking at this same thing for about an hour and couldn't find it. Thanks, I'll mark your answer as answered whenever possible!

Comment: @Jordy Glad to help - and it happens to us all!